# Slow download (and normal upload) on Ubuntu 18.04 wiredc Ethernet 1Gbps

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 desktop that was new a few years ago, but it is still a very capable machine, with 8 cores (i7-4790 + 16GB + 1TB SSD).

I recently switched to 18.04 and for some reason, my wired Internet connection via Ethernet (1Gbit/s NIC) is only able to pump down 18-20Mbps or so on download. It is able to saturate upload with 100Mbps. I have a 1G connection to my router (connected via two switches to my router, both 1Gbps switches). My ISP connection is symetric 100MBps/100Mbps. Just to check if my switch was the problem, I connected the same cable to my Mac which was able to saturate my ISP connection at 100Mbps.

My lshw -c network output looks like this:

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 0c
   serial: f8:bc:12:93:8e:19
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.045.08-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.40 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:30 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7200000-f7200fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
  *-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlp4s0
   version: 01
   serial: 90:48:9a:2e:ce:f7
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-44-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:16 memory:f7100000-f717ffff memory:f7180000-f718ffff
  *-network:0
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: br-763ed3b1d7a9
   serial: 02:42:df:43:a4:1c
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.20.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: br-5ae17914b506
   serial: 02:42:54:9d:cb:e5
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.21.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:2
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: docker0
   serial: 02:42:c4:10:1c:63
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:3
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 4
   logical name: br-2d05881c601d
   serial: 02:42:c5:00:33:c6
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.19.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:4
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 5
   logical name: br-6e918bada3df
   serial: 02:42:2c:4b:ab:96
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

FWIW, I also have docker running on this machine, though I fail to see why and how that should matter.

Does anyone know what is going on? I did add `r8168-dkms` and rebooted, though that seems to have done nothing to the issue.

Comment: Replace network cable? Bad hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently struggling with that same NIC, but in version 06.

My symptoms:

- "ethtool -S enp3s0" shows plenty of rx_errors.
- Download limited to 5Mbits variable.
- Other tools such as ifconfig do not report any rx error.
- I'm stuck with 100Mbits (While I have everything in GBits) - For that is seems your luckier than me.
- If I disable the full duplex (ethtool -s enp3s0 duplex half), this fixes the rx_errors, but not my speed problem. At least I get the 100Mbits.

So, first check if you see errors with ethtool -S enp3s0.

I tried to install the r8168-dkms package/module (then reboot). But it the same behaviour.

Also check:

```
root@pivert-desktop:~# modinfo r8168
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/updates/dkms/r8168.ko
version:        8.045.08-NAPI
```

In my case, since it takes it from /updates/dkms/, it's using the dkms driver.

```
root@pivert-desktop:~# lshw -C network   *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 06
       serial: bc:5f:f4:45:b7:34
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.045.08-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.232.34 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:35 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d4004000-d4004fff memory:d4000000-d4003fff
```

Comment: After changing ports, patch pannel port, patch... I finally changed the NIC with a USB one. And I still see errors, and frequent change to 100Mb or even 10Mb. My best guess is the patch pannel and patch plugs that are not properly connected, likely not using the proper pairs. I had the issue already at an other location. I'll check that in the next days with the eletrician.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my ethernet. I checked the download speed on the Windows platform, it was showing around 1 Gbps. Then I checked on Ubuntu, and it was 6 Mbps, and the upload speed was around 500 Mbps.
Trying so many solutions and not getting resolved was frustrating.
Then I updated my Linux kernel from 5.0.0.32 to 5.4.0.70. Now it is working fine and the downloading speed is same as Windows.